# python cassandra driver setting keyspace error

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am getting an error using the python driver for datastax's Cassandra when setting the keyspace.  here is my code up to the error:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.query import SimpleStatement
cluster = Cluster(['some.IP.addr'])
session = cluster.connect()
session.set_keyspace('demodb')
```

here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./forecasts.py", line 115, in <module>
    main()
  File "./forecasts.py", line 51, in main
    session.set_keyspace(KEYSPACE)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1255, in set_keyspace
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cassandra/cluster.py", line 995, in execute
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2195, in result
cassandra.connection.ConnectionException: Failed to set keyspace on all hosts:
[InvalidRequest(u'code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Keyspace \'weathertest\' does not exist"',), InvalidRequest(u'code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Keyspace \'weathertest\' doe
s not exist"',)]
```

and this is the log at DEBUG level:

```
DEBUG:root:
debugging is turned on
INFO:root:info is turned on

DEBUG:cassandra.pool:Host 10.10.0.51 is now marked up
DEBUG:cassandra.cluster:[control connection] Opening new connection to 10.10.0.51
DEBUG:cassandra.connection:Not sending options message for new connection(29704848) to 10.10.0.51 because compression is disabled and a cql version was not specified
DEBUG:cassandra.io.libevreactor:Starting libev event loop
DEBUG:cassandra.connection:Got ReadyMessage on new connection (29704848) from 10.10.0.51
DEBUG:cassandra.cluster:[control connection] Established new connection <LibevConnection(29704848) 10.10.0.51:9042>, registering watchers and refreshing schema and topology
DEBUG:cassandra.cluster:[control connection] Refreshing node list and token map
DEBUG:cassandra.cluster:[control connection] Found new host to connect to: 10.10.0.50
INFO:cassandra.cluster:New Cassandra host 10.10.0.50 added
DEBUG:cassandra.cluster:Adding or renewing pools for new host 10.10.0.50 and notifying listeners
DEBUG:cassandra.cluster:Done preparing queries for new host 10.10.0.50
DEBUG:cassandra.pool:Host 10.10.0.50 is now marked up
DEBUG:cassandra.cluster:[control connection] Fetched ring info, rebuilding metadata
DEBUG:cassandra.cluster:[control connection] Waiting for schema agreement
DEBUG:cassandra.cluster:[control connection] Schemas match
DEBUG:cassandra.cluster:[control connection] Fetched schema, rebuilding metadata
DEBUG:cassandra.cluster:Control connection created
DEBUG:cassandra.pool:Initializing new connection pool for host 10.10.0.51
DEBUG:cassandra.pool:Initializing new connection pool for host 10.10.0.50
DEBUG:cassandra.connection:Not sending options message for new connection(139755014785552) to 10.10.0.51 because compression is disabled and a cql version was not specified
DEBUG:cassandra.connection:Not sending options message for new connection(29756880) to 10.10.0.50 because compression is disabled and a cql version was not specified
DEBUG:cassandra.connection:Got ReadyMessage on new connection (139755014785552) from 10.10.0.51
DEBUG:cassandra.connection:Got ReadyMessage on new connection (29756880) from 10.10.0.50
DEBUG:cassandra.connection:Not sending options message for new connection(29754064) to 10.10.0.51 because compression is disabled and a cql version was not specified
DEBUG:cassandra.connection:Got ReadyMessage on new connection (29754064) from 10.10.0.51
DEBUG:cassandra.connection:Not sending options message for new connection(29754640) to 10.10.0.50 because compression is disabled and a cql version was not specified
DEBUG:cassandra.pool:Finished initializing new connection pool for host 10.10.0.51
DEBUG:cassandra.cluster:Added pool for host 10.10.0.51 to session
DEBUG:cassandra.connection:Got ReadyMessage on new connection (29754640) from 10.10.0.50
DEBUG:cassandra.pool:Finished initializing new connection pool for host 10.10.0.50
DEBUG:cassandra.cluster:Added pool for host 10.10.0.50 to session
INFO:root:setting keyspace...
DEBUG:cassandra.io.libevreactor:Closing connection (139755014785552) to 10.10.0.51
DEBUG:cassandra.io.libevreactor:Closing connection (29754064) to 10.10.0.51
DEBUG:cassandra.io.libevreactor:Closing connection (29756880) to 10.10.0.50
DEBUG:cassandra.io.libevreactor:Closing connection (29754640) to 10.10.0.50
DEBUG:cassandra.cluster:Shutting down Cluster Scheduler
DEBUG:cassandra.io.libevreactor:Closing connection (29704848) to 10.10.0.51
DEBUG:cassandra.cluster:Not executing scheduled task due to Scheduler shutdown
```

any insights would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Do you really have that ``'weathertest'`` on both of your nodes?

Comment: I would also make sure you're matching any capitalization on the keyspace name.

Answer (score 0):

Using `cqlsh` check and confirm your keyspace.

The keyspace in your script and which one you are trying to connect are different:

```
cqlsh> DESCRIBE keyspaces;
```